# Multiline text in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, text, multiline

I'm trying to include a multiline text in a dataframe cell, however R keeps reading the \n as a next row, resulting in row mismatches. If i change the 'code' input to a simple string, the code works fine.

Defined dataframe:

```
  df <- data.frame(
    "Id" = character(),
    "Name" = character(),
    "Code" = character()
  )
```

Adding new row:

```
NewRow <- data.frame(
  "Id" = Id,              # Simple string
  "Name" = Name,          # Simple string
  "Code" = Code           # Complex multiline string containing '#' and '\n' (10+ lines)
)
df <- rbind(df, NewRow)
```

Received error: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce your code, it is working fine `NewRow <- data.frame(
+   "Id" = "1",              # Simple string
+   "Name" = "ssd",          # Simple string
+   "Code" = "CDD"           # Complex multiline string containing '#' and '\n' (10+ lines)
+ )
> rbind(df, NewRow)#
  Id Name Code
1  1  ssd  CDD`

Comment: It is better to show an example that doesn't work i.e. using `dput`

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you for noting this, it actually helped me find the mistake in the code. I found that the multiline text object produced by a function was not presented properly, since it was returned while using the 'cat()' function. This apparently does not change the actual text, only the way it is printed in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you can try is to clean up the `Code` variable a bit, before adding it to the dataframe. In this sense, you can remove `\n` and `#` from the `Code` variable, and then add it inside the dataframe. For this you can use `stringr` and `dplyr`, to update the `Code` variable:

```
### Using the replace option: 
    Code <- Code %>% 
             str_replace_all("\\\n", "") %>% 
             str_replace_all("#", "")

### Using the remove option: 
    Code <- Code %>% 
             str_remove_all("\\\n") %>% 
             str_remove_all("#")
```

Comment: Many thanks Isaac! When cleaning up the multiline text output from the function, I found it was presented in the wrong way. See my comment on the main question. Thanks again!